# How can I list all key values in reactive redis (quarkus)?

Tags: java, redis, quarkus

I have a flow to get the keys. I use these keys to get their values, then the list of values (Promotion) must be returned.
The problem is how to join these two flows. Thanks for the help.

I created the first flow then I transformed it to obtain a "UNI", but the result of the second flow returns another "UNI", which does not let me create the promotion list.

Code:

```
    public Uni<List<Promotion>> listAll() {
        return this.reactiveRedisDataSource.key().keys("promo*")
                .onItem().ifNotNull()
                .transformToUni(keys -> {
                    LOGGER.info("listAll ::: keys ::: " + keys);
                    List<Promotion> promotions = new ArrayList<>();

                    promotions = keys.stream().map(key -> {
                        return this.reactiveRedisDataSource
                                .value(String.class, Promotion.class)
                                .get(key).await().indefinitely();
                    }).toList();

                    return Uni.createFrom().item(promotions);
                });
    }
```

ERROR:

```
The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-2
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your method is invoked from an HTTP endpoint returning a `Uni`.
Consequently, your method is called on the event loop (it returns a Uni, so Quarkus calls you on the event loop). Thus you cannot block. However, in the method, you use `await().indefinitely(),` which is blocking.

So, you need to avoid blocking:

```java
private final ReactiveKeyCommands<String> keys;
private final ReactiveValueCommands<String, Promotion> values;


public MyClass(ReactiveRedisDataSource reactiveRedisDataSource) {
        this.keys = reactiveRedisDataSource.key();
        this.values = reactiveRedisDataSource.value(Promotion.class);
}

public Uni<List<Promotion>> listAll() {
  return keys.keys("promo*")
      .onItem().transformToMulti(keys -> Multi.createFrom().items(keys.stream()))
      .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(values::get)
      .collect().asList();
}
```

`MyClass` is a bean. First, I initialize the Redis objects to access the keys and values. It avoids having to create these objects every time.

Then, the `listAll` starts by listing all the matching keys and then transforms the returned list into a `Multi` (and asynchronous stream of keys). You get a `Multi<String>`.  Note that the returned list cannot be `null.` For each item from that stream, we retrieve the value. The `transformToUniAndMerge` indicates that you will retrieve the values concurrently instead of sequentially. If the order is not important, I would recommend that. If the order matters, use `transformToUniAndConcatenate.` At that point, you get a `Multi<Promotion>`. To transform that into a `Uni<List<Promotion>>`, you use `collect().asList(),` which collects all the items into a list and returns it when the last item is read.